# I can't replicate this database model in Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm creating a product catalogue in Rails using data from Icecat product database. 
I have some problems to replicate the Category - FeatureGroup - Feature structure.

This is the schema of the database, you can ignore vocabulary and language because they are for translation.

[image]

And this is the xml file of every single product to use as reference

[XML Sample file](https://icecat.it/en/xml?productId=12295890)

In my rails app I create three models:

```
Category
FeatureGroup
Feature
```

And I add a many to many relation between `Category` and `FeatureGroup` and between `FeatureGroup` and `Feature`.

Basically I think that every category has many `FeatureGroups` and every FeatureGroup has many `Features`.

But in the XML file every feature node has this structure

```
<ProductFeature Localized="0" ID="150078803" Local_ID="0" Value="OLED" CategoryFeature_ID="85325" CategoryFeatureGroup_ID="26690"  ...
```

So basically the Feature doesn't belongs to a FeatureGroup but to `CategoryFeature_ID` and to `CategoryFeatureGroup_ID`

I assume these tables are the join table between Category and Feature and beetween Category and FeatureGroup but I cannot understand the schema. And I don't have any idea how to replicate this schema in my rails app database...

I try to import the data with a task but I have about 28410 feature for one group so I think that something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the feature_group table is used as a join table between the category_feature_group and the vocabulary tables. If you only need the Category and Feature models it seems to me you do not need the FeatureGroup model.

A feature has many categories through category_features. The category_feature table has a feature_id and a catid. So you can connect these two tables.

If you do need the feature_group table, you can find that through your category_features table and your category_feature_group table using the category_feature_group_id in the category_features table and the feature_group_id in the category_feature_group table.

Comment: I need the FeatureGroup. Features are grouped using FeatureGroup. I think they extract FeatureGroup for translation, CategoryFeatureGroup has one FeatureGroup.
At this moment the "name" of the featureGroup is inside featureGroup table...

Comment: Ok, you do not show that name field in your model so I assumed it was just a join table. There is no direct relation between a feature and a feature_group.

Comment: Yes I know. Basically my query should be

group = Category.first.category_feature_groups.first
group.feature_group.name (the name)
group.features (the features)

Comment: If you can create models for category_feature_group and category_feature you can use has_many through: in your models to let Rails automatically create joins in your queries.